# How to find the percent variation in Y is explained by X?

Tags: statistics, correlation, percentages

I know that the r^2 value for the data is 0.9832. Is there a way to use that value to find the percent variation in Y is explained by X? Or do I need to use the data given to me?

Comment: That's exactly what $r^2$ means. (Convert to a percentage if you like.)

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Doesn't  r^2 represent X by Y?

Comment: Perhaps you left out some words or something? Your comment isn't coherent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r^2*100$ is the percentage of variance explained by $X$.

When you regress $Y$ on $X$ you get $\hat{Y}=a+r\frac{s_y}{s_x}X$

And $Var(\hat{Y})=r^2Var(Y)$ from the above equation.

So $\frac{Var(\hat{Y})}{Var(Y)}*100=r^2*100$ is the percentage of variance explained by x.